# Problems with HP Notebooks

Tags: linux, laptop

Good day. We are using HP Notebook - HP EliteBook x360 1040 G7. It seems that on linux (any os - we tested on ubuntu, centos and some others), even on latest kernel, inner microphone does not work, the fingerprint sensor does not work and there some problems with functionality buttons (brightness adjustment, for example). It seems than problem is known among some notebooks (there is info on forums). And there is no solution. On windows there is no such problems. Maybe there is necessity to include some other drivers in kernel? or there are other solutions?

Comment: The question is very broad and appeals replies like: "mine works". Naturally, for my ProBook the only thing which doesn't work is bluetooth, but it's known this chip doesn't have driver for Linux. Everything else works, and that works on any HP laptop I've seen with Linux. Have you tried to investigate which exactly hardware you have, how it's configured? Did you carefully read `dmesg` boot output? Had you investigated `/sys` contents? For microphone, did you try to run `alsamixer` and unmute everything related (I doubt PulseAudio is smart enough to find and fix everything there by itself)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want windows, then you should install some additional apps, like PulseAudio Volume Control to solve the inner microphone issue